# Why is ColumnTransformer not taking transformer arguments when running?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to define custom transformers with parameters, and use them in a sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.
I do not understand why my custom transformers parameters are not taken into account when I run fit_transform() on the ColumnTransformer.

The script below shows an oversimplified example of the issue I'm facing. The console output of the script is:

```
TRUE
FALSE
------
FALSE
FALSE
```

Why are both BlankTransformers initialized with default value when I call for fit_transform?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin


class BlankTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, test_bool=False):
        if(test_bool):
            print("TRUE")
        else:
            print("FALSE")

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 10]]), 
                            columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(
      [('true', BlankTransformer(True), ['a', 'b']),
       ('false', BlankTransformer(False), ['c', 'd'])],
    remainder='passthrough')

print("------")

df = column_transformer.fit_transform(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the assignment of the `test_bool` boolean to `self` in the `__ init__` step. Once you have done that, you will get the expected results from your print statement:

```
def __init__(self, test_bool=False):
    self.test_bool = test_bool
    if self.test_bool:
        print("TRUE")
    else:
        print("FALSE")
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves it for my boolean example but not for my real case issue. I don't know if I should accept the answer in that case..?  EDIT: I guess I should, since the formulated issue is answered. I'll investigate further, based on your advice.

Comment: By the way, do you know why the `__init__` step is performed twice? My python is a little rusty, but my intuition is it should only be called upon object creation.

Comment: @H.Leger Because you are calling the BlankTransformer twice in your column_transformer

Comment: I meant to say: why is it performed four times in total (twice for each BlankTransformer call)?

Comment: As far as I understand, it is once per BlankTransformer call.. but twice per column_transformer call given that it has two BlankTransformer's in it